# Как шифровать длинное сообщение RSA

Tags: криптография, шифрование, rsa

В том случае, если шифруемое сообщение больше N-1, как с ним поступать? Разбить сообщение, что бы получились числа не более N-1 или по блокам, например 8 бит, и каждый блок зашифровать независимо друг от друга. Пытался найти стандарты, но в RFC 8017 ничего про это не написано (скорее всего плохо читал). В каких стандартах/ГОСТ'ах про это говорится?

Comment: Длинные сообщения обычно шифруют симметричным шифрованием

Comment: А ключ шифрования шифруется ассиметричным.

Answer (score 0):

Для шифрования длинных сообщений и файлов рекомендую использовать контейнеры.

Один из стандартных s/mime

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8551

Используется и в ГОСТовом шифровании и в импортном

https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/docs/smime.pdf

В стандарте очень много ссылок связанные стандарты.